# MySql Database Android app

Tags: android, jdbc

I have an android app that needs a Mysql database hosted on a server, what is the best way to communicate with the DB? Using a JDBC with my app, or sending a HTTP request to a PHP WebService?

here a link to how use JDBC with android:

http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/configuring-and-accessing-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-android-application/

Comment: consider that talking the DB directly from android means exposing your DB to the internet, embedding database account credentials in your app, potentially allowing ANYONE to completely bypass your app and run amok inside your DB. never **EVER** provide direct database access for remote apps. ALWAYS have an abstraction layer that can implement extra security

Answer (score 0):

you can directly communicate with the MySQL through JDBC,but what you have to do is keep all the database connections in a AsynTask